# Getting rid of Minefield (Firefox daily build)

Tags: uninstall, firefox

Now that Firefox 4.0 is out, I've removed Minefield that I had previously installed via mozilla-daily. My problemis that I can't get rid of it, I mean it still appears in Gnome Menu (with missin icon error), in right click context menu under "Open with" submenu. I checked Synaptic and there's no trace of firefox-4.0. How can I completely purge Minefield from my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that only the menu-entry of Minefield is left.

Go to Menu/System/Preferences/Menu and uncheck or delete the minefield-entry on the right (but not the Firefox entry :-)).

[image]

Comment: Already done, my problem now is with the right click context menu.